# Highcharts: Set y Axis Max and Min dynamically, and not at creation

Tags: highcharts

Short question : Is there a way to set `min/max` in Highcharts AFTER the chart has been created. I am aware of intial setup like `y: {min: 100,max: 200}` at the chart initialization but I want to change max/min later on dynamically.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I guess [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes) is the best way to go about it. 
Syntax should be: `chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(100,300);`

If one wants to just set minimum then `chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(100,null);` worked for me.

Comment: great answer, saved me a lot of time

Comment: For those using angular-highcharts-ng (last version) it's $scope.chartConfig.getChartObj().xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max);

Comment: React: I used this in the componentDidUpdate method, current values used in this method are saved in state and don't forget to use UNIX timestamp in case you want to use dates on x axis

Answer (score 47):

we can also use update method

```
chart.yAxis[0].update({
    max: 100
}); 

chart.xAxis[0].update({
    max: 150
});
```

Comment: this worked for me, accepted answer did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner to define min/max values and ticks between these values.